# App crashing without reason

Tags: java, android

I just updated my app on the play store and i started receiving crash reports from people, one was a person i know, so he started helping me to solve this problem, and i discovered that the problem is caused by something i didn't even modify.

The code looks like this
The part that's causing the problem is the bulb.onClickListener

```
    public class Bulb extends Activity {

    public boolean isAwake = false;
    boolean timerActivated = false;
    static ImageView glow;
    public static boolean bulbActIsRunning = false;

      public void startWake() {
        Intent wS=new Intent(getBaseContext(), WakeService.class);
        startService(wS);
      }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton bulb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bulb);
        ImageButton ghl = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ghl);
        glow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glow);

        if (WakeService.isAwake) {
            glow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            glow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        bulb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startWake();

                if (WakeService.isAwake) {
                    glow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    glow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }        
           }
        });

        ghl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.geekshavelanded.com/"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
           }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        glow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glow);

        if (WakeService.isAwake) {
            glow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            glow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       bulbActIsRunning = true;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       bulbActIsRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

After my friends clicks the bulb button the app crashes without reason, i've put some toast notification at the beginning of the onClickListener to see if it appeared before crashing, but it didn't

The crash reports look like this

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.doublep.wakey.WakeService@41740bb8 with Intent { cmp=com.doublep.wakey/.WakeService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2933)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1438)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1436)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1384)
at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.updateAppWidgetIds(IAppWidgetService.java:513)
at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:333)
at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:400)
at com.doublep.wakey.WakeService.keepAwake(WakeService.java:86)
at com.doublep.wakey.WakeService.onStartCommand(WakeService.java:48)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2912)
... 10 more
```

Can anyone see something suspicious?
I didn't even touch the code of this activity when i was updating my app, and everything else works fine, because i can call the service from a widget aswell.
So the problem must be here

I also modified the min SDK from 8 to 7 (but to see if it works i've put it back to 8)
And i compressed some graphics a little bit more to save space

**EDIT** oh i forgot to say, this happens only to few devices, on most it seems working fine

**UPDATE 2** this is the piece of code that caused those issues

```
    AppWidgetManager mgr=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
 mgr.updateAppWidget(ToggleWidget.appWidgetId, ToggleWidget.remoteViews);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what line 86 and line 48 of WakeService are?

Comment: A `NullPointerException` *is* a reason ;)

Comment: Lines 48 and 86 are logs, the 48 is from an if else statement, the code from the else statement generates the log from 48 and runs a method, this method contains the log 86, which is written after a wakelock

WakeService is called from a widget aswell, so it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the parameter to updateAppWidget(). Ether remote view is null or you are setting null bitmap.

Comment: I have this in WakeService
`private void updateWidget(){
        retreiveIds();
        Log.w("Wakey", "Widget update"+ ids);
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ToggleWidget.class);
        intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
       // int[] ids = ids;
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }`

And this in the widget
`appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);`

Comment: Also i had this which was useless and forgot to delete 
`AppWidgetManager mgr=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
          mgr.updateAppWidget(ToggleWidget.appWidgetId, ToggleWidget.remoteViews);`

Comment: @DoubleP90 Please update the question instead of dumping code into comments, where it's essentially impossible to read.

Comment: @DaveNewton forgive me, this was the reson my app wasn't working, due to the second comments code